# How to integrate Google places Api into our application?

Tags: iphone

iam developing one application.In that i want to use the google places api.I written the url and established the connection like

```
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDbiWWIOmc08YSb9DAkdyTWXh_PirVuXpM"];
NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:URL];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

But in did finish loading delegate method i cant get the data.That code is here.
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
[connection release];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseDataencoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc]init];  
    NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil]; 

}
```

So please tell me where i did the mistake.Why iam not getting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ASIHTTPRequest framwork all these problems are automatically handle

all you have to do is just create a url
and parse the response using JSON framework

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge there are few mistaks.

1. `NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseDataencoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

The words **responseData encoding** are two world. I don't know whether you have pasted like that.

2. And I hope you have used `-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` delegates to append data to responseData object.
3. I think you do not need to cast to NSDictionary. You can use following code.

   `NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseDate bytes] length:[responseDate length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
   `NSLog(@"Data  = %@", content);`
   `NSError *error;`
   `SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];`
   `NSDictionary *jsonD = [parser objectWithString:content error:&error];`